# Memory leak with web audio api oscillator

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, web-audio-api

http://codepen.io/superuntitled/pen/EjZOjw/?editors=001

I have a little web instrument (see link above) that has a memory leak, and I am unsure how to plug it.

The following function is called when an element is hovered over (there are a couple hundred of these).

```
function tone(id, freq, tonelength) {

  gainNodes.id = audioCtx.createGain();
  osc.id = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  osc.id.connect(gainNodes.id);
  // set frequency and gain
  osc.id.frequency.value = freq;
  osc.id.start(0);

  gainNodes.id.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  gainNodes.id.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(.1, audioCtx.currentTime);

  gainNodes.id.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime + parseFloat(tonelength));

}
```

I think that duplicate oscillators are being created, but am not sure how to check if this is the case, or how to avoid it.

I have a feeling I should check to see if the oscillator already exists, and just run the gain, but I am not sure how to do that.

I have tried to stop the oscillator after it's duration, but this does not seem to stop the leak: http://codepen.io/superuntitled/pen/rVmqYX?editors=001

```
osc.id.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + parseFloat(tonelength));
```

Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with `osc.id` is a little weird, since you're setting `id` as a property name instead of `osc[ id ]` – but leaving that part aside, you'd want to add this to the bottom of your `tone()` function:

```
var current = osc.id;

current.stop( audioCtx.currentTime + 2 );

current.onended = function() {
  current.disconnect();
};
```

That basically says "Stop playing after 2 seconds, and when you're done, disconnect yourself from the AudioContext".

If `id` was dynamically assigned to `osc` (e.g. `osc[ id ]`), then you'd likely also need to `delete osc[ id ]` – but that seems to just be getting overridden each time `tone()` is called with the way you have it now – so the old oscillator should become eligible for garbage collection.

The reason for the `current` variable is that by the time `onended` fires, `osc.id` will likely have been reassigned – so you need a reference to the original oscillator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the disconnect in `onended` is useless. Since `OscillatorNode`s cannot be reused, processing stops when the time passed to `stop` has been reached. Then it gets collected and is automatically disconnected, granted you drop all the references to it in your code.

But that's a detail, it does not hurt in any way.

Comment: Makes sense. I couldn't remember if `AudioContext.destination` held a reference to nodes that connected to it. Thinking about it further, it's pretty obvious that would be a terrible idea. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the help Kevin, I think that I can take this and work with it. I appreciate your help on this.